# How to implement long running gRPC async streaming data updates in C++ server

Tags: c++, asynchronous, streaming, grpc

I'm creating an async gRPC server in C++. One of the methods streams data from the server to clients - it's used to send data updates to clients. The frequency of the data updates isn't predictable. They could be nearly continuous or as infrequent as once per hour. The model used in the gRPC example with the "CallData" class and the CREATE/PROCESS/FINISH states doesn't seem like it would work very well for that. I've seen an [example](https://www.gresearch.co.uk/article/lessons-learnt-from-writing-asynchronous-streaming-grpc-services-in-c/) that shows how to create a 'polling' loop that sleeps for some time and then wakes up to check for new data, but that doesn't seem very efficient.

Is there another way to do this? If I use the "CallData" method can it block in the 'PROCESS' state until there's data (which probably wouldn't be my first choice)? Or better, can I structure my code so I can notify a gRPC handler when data is available?

Any ideas or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a server-side streaming example, you probably need more states, because you need to track whether there is currently a write already in progress.  I would add two states, one called WRITE_PENDING that is used when a write is in progress, and another called WRITABLE that is used when a new message can be sent immediately.  When a new message is produced, if you are in state WRITABLE, you can send immediately and go into state WRITE_PENDING, but if you are in state WRITE_PENDING, then the newly produced message needs to go into a queue to be sent after the current write finishes.  When a write finishes, if the queue is non-empty, you can grab the next message from the queue and immediately start a write for it; otherwise, you can just go into state WRITABLE and wait for another message to be produced.

There should be no need to block here, and you probably don't want to do that anyway, because it would tie up a thread that should otherwise be polling the completion queue.  If all of your threads wind up blocked that way, you will be blind to new events (such as new calls coming in).

An alternative here would be to use the C++ sync API, which is much easier to use.  In that case, you can simply write straight-line blocking code.  But the cost is that it creates one thread on the server for each in-progress call, so it may not be feasible, depending on the amount of traffic you're handling.

I hope this information is helpful!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've experimented with a few things and I'm currently using an observer pattern. My subscribe handler object (derived from the 'CallData' object as in the gRPC async example) signs up for notifications from a data producer thread. When data is available the subscribe handler is notified. In my current implementation that sets an alarm object in the grpc completion queue which expires immediately. The stream write occurs during the callback of the alarm. That works although it's probably not the way the alarm is meant to be used. I may try your approach too. Thanks.

Comment: @Mark D. Roth is there an example of C++ async solution for streams or C++ sync with threads ?

Comment: This example doesn't use threads, but it basically works the same way it would if it did:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/cpp/helloworld/greeter_async_server.cc

You can have as many threads as you want polling the completion queues and executing the corresponding callbacks.